# Ubuntu won't shut down

Tags: dell, 64-bit, shutdown

I upgraded to 64 bit 16.04 from 32 bit 14.04 about a month or two ago. I had no problems until the update. When I updated my computer had a slow boot but would still shut down correctly. I cut the boot time from 1:50 to 36 seconds just by using "Quiet Splash" Soon after this problem was solved my computer started hanging on shutdown. I turned it off like I regularly do from the drop-down menu. I thought that the computer was just taking its time so I left it running for over 30 minutes and it still was showing the Ubuntu splash screen. Since this occured I have been forcing shutdown by holding the power button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into /etc/default/grub and add "acpi=off" after "quiet splash" in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable. Mine looks like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"

Be advised, this might not work. I fixed my issue with this at first but I think issue started again after I ran "sudo apt-get update" or upgrade at some point. I still haven't fixed mine. Just might work for you. I'd really appreciate the answer to this problem as well. Cheers!